# Sign message not showing up on Metamask app

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, metamask

I'm working on a website very much similar to https://relative.fi . Now, when I open this on my mobile browser and try connecting my wallet using metamask, it is redirecting me to metamask but not showing the sign message pop-up.

This wasn't the case a few months ago but I'm not able to find any update on rainbowkit either
I'm using rainbowkit for the auth in my website too just like relative.fi.

Any code fixes for this?

Comment: This is likely because of a lot of wallets and related libraries having issues with WalletConnect 2.0 migration. You need to make the issue repeatable with a code example and then take this code example to MetaMask dev support.

Comment: Correct, that was indeed the cause of the issues along with the fact that my rainbowkit was running on an older version. I've updated it and it's working fine now.